# RestClient using Resource for GET action

Tags: ruby, rest

I am writing a ruby client for the REST API using RestClient gem. While going through examples, I see different code used to achieve basically the same result, without any explanation on the difference.

```
client = RestClient::Resource.new('https://example.com/')
response = client.get
```

VS

```
response = RestClient.get('https://example.com/')
```

What is the benefit of using `Resource` class, if I can achieve same thing with `get` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code reuse. It's especially useful when you're dealing with APIs, and you need to hit the same base urls over and over, with different params and/or paths. As the docs show you, once you build a base resource:

```
client = RestClient::Resource.new('https://example.com/')
```

You can access other paths under this resource quite easily:

```
response = client["/users/1"].get
```

Which is equivalent to

```
response = RestClient.get("https://example.com/users/1")
```

but less typing/repetition.